# Can eval be avoided in nested [:a,:b].each{loops}?

Tags: ruby, eval

Is there any way to use native ruby methods or maybe a library to do what I just did. And I found about eval and it blew my mind how easily I could implement my solution.

I know eval isn't ideal because the danger of arbitrary code injection. Which I don't think could happen in this program, but I always like to be on the safe side.

My first idea was to use a tree structure, but that didn't work because I don't know enough about trees and how to iterate over them. I also tried a nested hash, but ended using eval to populate it too, and I still had to figure out how to iterate over it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This programs generates guesses for forgoten passwords
guesses   = []
passwords = []

# Read user input and generate a series of guesses.
nth = 1
print "Guess number 1:"

while guess = gets
    nth += 1
    print "Guess number #{nth}:"
    guesses << guess.chomp.split('')
end

# Generate an expression by dequeuing guesses.
first_string    = ""                
second_string   = "passwords << ''" 
letter          = 101               # First ASCII character
counter = 0

guesses.count.times do 

    # Dequeuing
    shifted_array   =   guesses.shift

    # FIFO loops
    first_string    +=  "#{shifted_array}.each{ |#{letter.chr}| "

    # Concatenates each of the permutations of the guesses
    second_string   +=  ".+(#{letter.chr})"

    letter          += 1 # Next ASCII character
    counter         += 1
end

# Adds ending braces
final_string = first_string + second_string + ('}'*counter)

# Evaluates string populating passwords array
print "\n"
eval final_string


passwords.each{|x| puts x }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Apart from the above, the code you posted does not work. :) And yes, there (almost) always is a better way then eval. Please move this question to codereview, I think it should be possible to do this in top of 5 lines.

Comment: I'm a n00b, I didn't know there was a codereview.stackexchange.com sorry. Is there a way to migrate the question with the answers? They already answered me here, I don't see the point of wasting anybody's time on codereview.

Comment: Don't worry about this. The only problem with posting it here rather than there is that there is not getting enough attention/problems. I think mods still can migrate it, don't know hoe to ask them for it though. :(

Comment: BTW it works you just have to put Ctrl-D after inputing the initial guesses. It's horribly made I concur but it does work. I waited until I had a working example, before I had you guys rip it apart. As they say in gaming "game experience may change during online play" because you can be chainsaw n00b3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerables are quite powerful and worth learning. If I understand your problem correctly, this does the same thing:

```
$stdin.each_line
      .map { |guess| guess.chomp.chars }
      .inject(&:product)
      .each { |pass| puts pass.join }
```

Comment: I didn't know the inject method, thanks!

Comment: It's also called `reduce` in more functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Believe it or not, setting a variable to an initial value and then working on it in a loop is a code smell in Ruby. That is, a sign that you might be on the wrong track.

Have a look at the methods "map" and "reduce" for starters. If you get stuck understanding them, look for a basic introduction to functional programming.

Some quick examples:

```
[1, 2, 3].map {|x| x + 1 }       # -> [2,3,4]
[1, 2, 3].reduce {|x,m| m += x}  # -> 6
```

Then if you get the hang of that, look at lambdas too, but chances are you can solve this one by just using map.

Also, look at breaking down your code into different discrete jobs and making each a function. Your code will be a little longer, but *lots* easier to work on.

Comment: I didn't know initializing values was a codesmell. I knew I was doing procedural programming, but since it was just a script I was going to figure out the logic and clean it up afterwards. Thanks.